# running script on server from putty

Tags: linux, bash, cron, putty

I have to run a script file which takes a bit long time. I am using putty on window and I need to run the script on linux server.

I cannot run the server directly on windows as I may need to shutdown the windows machine, one way is to use cronjob?

Can we have some other alternatives for the same?

Comment: You can try to deattach the script process from the bash instance you are logged in with.

Comment: @hamon sound great! Can you please explain it, as i am new to linux.

Comment: have a look at: http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3935306/Detach-Processes-With-Disown-and-Nohup.htm

Comment: @hamon Thanks!! This article is great and it is best option!! although nohup will is also work!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the screen or even better the tmux program. They can continue to run when you disconnect (=detach) and you can re-attach later on.

Answer (score 0):

Use **nohup**:

```
nohup command &
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if this will work "nohup myscript.sh &"? As  don't have access to Linux server right now